# Freemarker - HTTPSession attribute returning null

Tags: java, jersey, freemarker

We have a jersey based web application. We use Apache Freemarker for the front end web pages. I have created a servlet Filter and added it in out web.xml. 
This filter intercepts all the http requests. In the doFilter method of that Filter, I am getting the HTTPSession from the request object and setting
an attribute value. Say "myVal".

myVal should now be set on the HTTPSession in the HTTPServletRequest. How can I access this myVal in the FTL page. 
I tried to find some posts on how to retrieve the
session and it is always returning null.

I have updated Freemarker to the latest version: 2.3.28

I have also tried adding the servlet[1] mentioned in the Freemarker documentation to my web.xml.

Tried the following ways to access the myVal:

${Request.myVal}

${myVal}

${Request.Session.myVal}

${Session.myVal}

All the above values are "null" and the below exception is thrown

FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> Request [in template "home.ftl" at line 18, column 3]

---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, 
or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: 
(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${Request.Session.user_privilages} 
[in template "home.ftl" at line 18, column 1]

Comment: How is FreeMarker configured? How is it invoked? How is it supposed to know about the request and/or session objects? Or any other values for that matter?

Comment: On the application start up, we do:  register(FreemarkerMvcFeature.class); on the ResourceConfig. and we use the jersey-mvc-freemarker jar. From the front end we make ajax calls to  our REST server, it returns a Viewable with a ftl name and all needed details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in the [source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/ext/mvc-freemarker/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/freemarker), `jersey-mvc-freemarker` does not add any extra values to the FreeMarker model.

That means it can only see what you add. If you want the template to see the `Session`, then you need to add `Session` to the model.

Comment: As per the freemarker [documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html) .. it looks like we could access the request object in the FTL pages

Comment: @HarshaThota This question is about using the `jersey-mvc-freemarker` library to add "view" support for FreeMarker templates to the Jersey MVC framework, and has *nothing* to do with making FreeMarker templates act like JSPs in a Servlet Container, which is what that documentation is about.